# C#: Controlling a power supply using VISA libraries and the device USB-TP PIA4850. Not able to read the power supply output properly

Tags: c#, visa

I am tring to control  a power supply (from Kikusui), using the Kikusui device, USB-TP PIA4850. I use the library, Ivi.Visa.Interop. Following is the code where I  am succesfully able to control the power supply, by setting the desired voltage.

(Link to programming guide: https://www.kikusui.co.jp/kiku_manuals/P/PIA4800/english/index.html)

(Link to operation manual: https://www.kikusui.co.jp/kiku_manuals/P/PIA4850_E5.pdf)

```
Using Ivi.Visa.Interop;
namespace USBTPTest
{
class USBTPController
{

private IResourceManager3 rm = new ResourceManager();
private IMessage iMessage;

public USBTPController() //to get the address of the device connected and open the address if found
    {
        string[] adrsList = rm.FindRsrc("?*");
        if (adrsList.Count() != 0)
        {
            Open(adrsList[0]);
        }
    }

public bool Open(string str)
    {
        string addr = str;
        iMessage = (IMessage)rm.Open(addr, AccessMode.NO_LOCK, 0, "");

        //iMessage.WriteString("TRM 2");
        iMessage.WriteString("NODE 5");
        iMessage.WriteString("CH 1");
        iMessage.WriteString("REM 1");
        bOpened = true;
        return true;
    }

public bool SetVoltage(float vol) {} //method to set the desired voltage to the power supply, when called with an appropriate argument
```

The set voltage is checked by a multimeter on the power supply terminals. Similarly current is also set and checked. Until here the code runs and gives the expected results.

```
public string ReadVOut()
    {
        iMessage.WriteString("VOUT?"); //Query OUT(ON/OFF) measurement value
        string VOutStatus;
        VOutStatus = iMessage.ReadString(1024); //Read from PIA
        return VOutStatus;
    }
public string ReadIOut()
    {

        iMessage.WriteString("IOUT?"); //Query OUT(ON/OFF) measurement value
        string COutStatus;
        COutStatus = iMessage.ReadString(1024); //Read from PIA
        return COutStatus;

    }
}
}
```

The problem occurs when I read the voltage/current values being outputted. Although I am able to read the values correctly, sometimes reading Voltage using ReadVOut() gives current and vice versa. I am not able to figure out if its a fault in the code or in the power supply I am connected to, or something else. And kind of help/ideas/leads would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this question still actual? Do I understand it correctly that you use two instruments both controlled via USB? ReadVOut & ReadIOut are always called from same thread? Just a guess: can it be that for some reason you don't read out a reply to one query, then make another query but read the response to the previous query while two responses are already available?